# SetClrFeatureSwitchMap not found in DLL "SqlServerSpatial110.dll"

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2012 and try to insert a Polygon in a Table Column of type "geometry". If I call

```
INSERT INTO GeoTable VALUES 
(
'Test',
geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 160, 80 210, 140 210, 140 150, 90 0, 0 0))', 0)

);
```

I got an entry point "SetClrFeatureSwitchMap" not found in DLL "SqlServerSpatial110.dll". System.EntryPointNotFoundException.

How can I solve that problem?

Thanks and regards

Comment: try another version of : SqlServerSpatial110.dll

Answer (score 3):

Verify that both dll's are in your `bin` folder:

- msvcr100.dll
- SqlServerSpatial110.dll

and have this in your web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

My SQL Server Version was 11.0.2100.60. After an update to SQL Server SP3 the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, installing higher version of SQL Server CLR Types (for example 2019 which is v.15) and changing the .config file like below fixed the issue.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```