# 'SetClrFeatureSwitchMap gives me an error when i save data in database

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, entity-framework

My application, win form in c#, in visual studio 2012,with entity framework 5,using oracle 11g, in only one pc crashes when i save or update database (in all other pc it works fine)
in this pc gives me this error

Unable to find an entry point named 'SetClrFeatureSwitchMap' in DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'.

i attach an image to the crash error

[image]

i have tried to update sql server 2012 at service pack 4 but error is always present; this pc has windows 10 in 64 bit

Comment: could you please at least translate the exception message into english

Comment: Unable to find an entry point named 'SetClrFeatureSwitchMap' in DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'.

Comment: Check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527471/setclrfeatureswitchmap-not-found-in-dll-sqlserverspatial110-dll
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204990/entity-framework-cannot-update-database